# What is a simple explanation for how to solve this simplified raindrop fall problem?

Tags: atmospheric-science

This is a problem for an atmospheric science class, but my question is physical in nature:

> A raindrop with an initial radius $r_i$ evaporates while falling through the atmosphere.
>
> Its evaporation is modeled by
>
> $r\frac{dr}{dt}=G_l{\cdot}S\:\:\:(1)$
>
> Where $G_l$ is a constant that takes into account ventilation of heat and moisture due to the falling drop, and $S$ is supersaturation, also constant.
>
> Its velocity is modeled by
>
> $V=\frac{dx}{dt}=A{\cdot}r\:\:\:(2)$
>
> Where $A$ is also constant.
>
> How long will it take for the raindrop to fall a distance $x_f$?

I solved the problem by first integrating $(1)$ with respect to $t$, obtaining an equation for $r_f$(final radius) as a function of $t$, and then substituting that for the $r$ in $(2)$. I then integrated with respect to $t$ again and rearranged for the solution.

However, others took the method of rearranging $(1)$ in terms of $dt$ and then substituting that into $(2)$ and integrating from 0 to $x_f$ to obtain the final radius $r_f$. Then, equation (1) was integrated from $r_i$ to $r_f$ to obtain the final time $t_f$. This method resulted in vastly different results. It seemed odd that one could obtain the final radius before the final time when, I believe, the radius is just dependent upon the time for evaporation to occur.

I think the problem with the method used by others is that it assumes $\frac{dx}{dt}$ in $(2)$ can be rewritten as $\frac{dx}{dr}\frac{dr}{dt}$, but that cannot be the case because the radius of the raindrop $r$ is not directly a function of displacement $x$ but is only directly a function of $t$. In other words, the radius is a function of $V$ but not of $x$.

Am I correct, and is there a better way to explain this?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that in the second method you write Eq. 2 as $\frac{d x}{d r} \frac{d r}{d t} = A r$, and substitute $\frac{d r}{d t}$ from Eq. 1? That procedure is fine, but it will give you $x$ as a function of $r$, but not its time-dependence (which is what you need).

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez I have edited the question to clarify the second method.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez But yes that is correct.

Comment: Using the two methods, I get the same answer in both cases.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez You're right